# Mouseover on element - do something / Mouseout on parent (or other) element - undo something?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here... 
I put a wrapper around a menu that I want to drop-down when one of the menu items is hovered, I also want it to stay open only until the mouse leaves the drop-down area, not the when it leaves the menu item.

JQUERY:

```
var hov = 1;
$( "#link-a" ).mouseover(function(){
    clearTimeout();
    hov = 1;
    $( "#dropdown" ).addClass( "active" );
});

$( "#dropdown" ).mouseout(function(){
    hov = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(hov == 0){
            $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li id="link-a">Link A</li>
        <li id="link-b">Link B</li>
        <li id="link-c">Link C</li>
    </ul>            
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dropdown {
    height: 0;
}
#dropdown.active {
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: can you edit http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9Jh36/2/ to recreate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are really looking for is [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event instead of [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#link-a").mouseover(function () {
        $("#dropdown").addClass("active");
    });

    $("#dropdown").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9Jh36/)

Comment: Thank you. This seemed to be the only solution to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple indeed. You're missing the `#` to indicate "element with ID of.." at `$( "link-a" )`

```
$( "#link-a" ).mouseover(function(){
    clearTimeout();
    hov = 1;
    $( "#dropdown" ).addClass( "active" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hov = 1;
var timer; //declare variable named timer accessible to both function below
$("#link-a").mouseover(function(){
// ^ missing # for id-selector
    clearTimeout(timer); //clear timer
    hov = 1;
    $( "#dropdown" ).addClass( "active" );
});

$("#dropdown").mouseout(function(){
    hov = 0;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ //assign setTimeout to variable timer
        if(hov == 0){
            $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

---

If you want to add mouse over to all li tags inside `#dropdown`

```
$("#dropdown li").mouseover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer); //clear timer
    hov = 1;
    $("#dropdown").addClass( "active" );
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I just couldn't get this to work properly. The drop-down would stay open when I mousedout and I couldn't figure out why. But thanks.